# ng2-translate directive not working while pipe is

Tags: angular, angular-directive, ng2-translate, angular-pipe

[Ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) `directive` is causing me some issues, but I don't get if I'm doing something wrong or if it's a bug.

On the same component's `html` template, the translate `pipe` is working, while the translate `directive` is not.

In particular:

```
<span translate>{{ feature.linkTxt }}</span> // works

<span [translate]="feature.linkTxt"></span> // not working
```

see https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate#4-use-the-service-the-pipe-or-the-directive

Am I missing something or should it work?

EDIT

The variable `feature.linkTxt` points to the `string` `LEARNMORE`, which corresponds to the following `json` string:

```
"LEARNMORE": "Learn more",
```

If I switch from the directive to the pipe, with the same variable, the translated text is displayed.

The `feature.linkTxt` variable is generated by the following `*ngFor` statement:

```
<li *ngFor="let feature of featureslist"> ...
```

Comment: are you getting any error for using it?

Comment: @ranakrunal9 no errors whatsoever, the text is just not translated and the DOM element is left without text

Comment: can you share you language json file object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is a known open bug.

See https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate/issues/355

Answer (score 0):

As per [ng2-translate example](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate#4-use-the-service-the-pipe-or-the-directive) if your language file is as below :

```
{
  HELLO: 'hello {{value}}'
}
```

Then you should use it like :

```
// there is single quote foe HELLO inside [translate]
<div [translate]="'HELLO'" [translateParams]="{value: 'world'}"></div>
```

So i think your json is like : `{ feature : { linkTxt : 'Your Text' } }` and for it you should use it like :

```
<span [translate]="'feature.linkTxt'"></span>
```

Comment: In my case `feature.linkTxt` is a variable that is generated in a `ngFor` loop, that is why I don't have the `' '` around it.

Comment: Have you tried `<span translate>feature.linkTxt</span>` ?

Comment: `feature.linkTxt` is a variable, so I've tried `<span translate>{{ feature.linkTxt }}</span>` and that is working. Apparently it is a bug, I'm adding a response for this.